# OR results from series of boolean-returning methods

Tags: java

I have a series of methods, each processing unique business rules, and each return a boolean result. I need ALL the methods executed, but if any one of them returns a true, then additional processing is required on dependent data. So, I can't just do:

```
boolean bizRuleFailed = false;
bizRuleFailed = methOneRule(data) || methTwoRule(data) || methThreeRule(data);
```

because it would stop after the first true-result method. So I am doing this:

```
boolean bizRuleFailed = false;
bizRuleFailed = methOneRule(data) || bizRuleFailed;
bizRuleFailed = methTwoRule(data) || bizRuleFailed;
bizRuleFailed = methThreeRule(data) || bizRuleFailed;
```

, which is far from ideal. What's a good way to do this instead? Thanks

Comment: Use `|` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you are using, `||` is called a *Logical Or* (or alternatively an *Or Else*) operator, which means that if the left-hand expression evaluates to true, the right-hand expression **will not** be evaluated.

Instead, use the standard *Bitwise Or* operator, `|`, which will cause all expressions to be evaluated before the result is determined:

```
bizRuleFailed = methOneRule(data) | methTwoRule(data) | methThreeRule(data);
```

Comment: thank you. that was what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use the bitwise `|` instead of the logical `||`. This doesn't short circuit and providing you're comparing boolean values they are otherwise identical.

```
boolean bizRuleFailed = methOneRule(data) | methTwoRule(data) | methThreeRule(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 bizRuleFailed |= methOneRule(data);
 bizRuleFailed |= methTwoRule(data);
 bizRuleFailed |= methThreeRule(data);
```

Or shorter

```
 bizRuleFailed = methOneRule(data) |  methTwoRule(data) | methThreeRule(data);
```